# jQuery button value

Tags: jquery, button

I have a button `("#btnchangepass")`, the value of the button is `"show"`. If i click the button the value must change in `"hide"`, if I click the button another time the value must change as it was at the beginning in `"show"`.

I wrote this code, but i don't know how I can get back the beginning value of the button. Can someone give me a hand?

The button is not hide, it's just the value of the button, the name displayed on the button is `hide` and `show`.

```
$('#btnshowhide').click(function(){
    $("#btnshowhide").prop('value', 'hide');
});
```

Comment: You can't click an hidden element, so if you hide it you need to click  another visible item to show it again.

Comment: @Michelem op want to change the value of button, not show and hide.

Comment: oh my bad I didn't understand that

Comment: The button is not hide, it's just the value of the button, the name displayed on the button is hide and show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for its state and change the value accordingly:

```js
$('#btnshowhide').click(function () {
    if ($("#btnshowhide").val() == 'show') {
        $("#btnshowhide").prop('value', 'hide');
    } else {
        $("#btnshowhide").prop('value', 'show');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btnshowhide" value="show" />
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q44oo9ss/)

Comment: Yess, you are the only one that really understood the question, thank you very much! :)

Comment: I don't think I was the only one but hey, glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery < 1.8 use:

```
$('#btnshowhide').toggle(function () {
    $("#btnshowhide").attr('value', 'hide');
}, function () {
    $("#btnshowhide").attr('value', 'show');
});
```

Else, if you just wanna hide the button and show, use ternary operators:

```
$('#btnshowhide').click(function () {
    $(this).attr('value', $(this).attr('value') == 'hide' ? 'show' : 'hide');;
});
```

Use `.attr()` instead of `.prop()`, as the latter is used for mostly boolean stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#btnshowhide').click(function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val() === 'show' ? 'hide' : 'show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btnshowhide" value="show" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `hide()`

```
$('#btnshowhide').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

UPDATED:

Sorry I didn't understand, so you need something like this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/g8mfhr88/)

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="hide" id="btnshowhide" />
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnshowhide').click(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "hide") {
            $(this).val("show");
        } else {
            $(this).val("hide");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Changing button value, not hiding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```js
$('#btnshowhide').click(function() {
  $(this).prop('value', $(this).prop('value') == 'hide' ? 'show' : 'hide');
  alert('This has val ' + $(this).prop('value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnshowhide">button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `data` attribute:

```
$('#btnshowhide').click(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    var newVal = "";

   if(val === "hide") {
      newVal = $(this).data("show-text");
   } else {
     newVal = $(this).data("hide-text");
   }

   $(this).val(newVal);
});
```